# Where is actual parameter are passed?

Tags: android, cordova

I am working in phonegap with android. I want to upload my file to my server. i have taken help from this link :- https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/FileUploader

This is my **fileupload.java** code:

```
package com.beetight;

import com.phonegap.*;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class fileupload extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

This is my **fileuploader.java** class:

```
package com.beetight;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import android.net.Uri;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;

import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;

/**
* @author matt
*
*/
public class FileUploader extends Plugin {

/* (non-Javadoc)
* @see com.phonegap.api.Plugin#execute(java.lang.String, org.json.JSONArray, java.lang.String)
*/
@Override
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {

try {
String server = args.getString(0);
String file = args.getString(1);
JSONObject params = args.getJSONObject(2);

String fileKey = "file";
String fileName = "image.jpg";
String mimeType = "image/jpeg";
if(args.length() > 3) {
fileKey = args.getString(3);
}
if(args.length() > 4) {
fileName = args.getString(4);
}
if(args.length() > 5) {
mimeType = args.getString(5);
}

if (action.equals("upload")) {
upload(file, server, params, fileKey, fileName, mimeType, callbackId);
} else if (action.equals("uploadByUri")) {
Uri uri = Uri.parse(file);
upload(uri, server, params, fileKey, fileName, mimeType, callbackId);
} else {
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
}
PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
r.setKeepCallback(true);
return r;
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
}

}

public void upload(Uri uri, String server, JSONObject params, final String fileKey, final String fileName, final String mimeType, String callbackId) {
try {
InputStream fileInputStream=this.ctx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
upload(fileInputStream, server, params, fileKey, fileName, mimeType, callbackId);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
}

public void upload(String filename, String server, JSONObject params, final String fileKey, final String fileName, final String mimeType, String callbackId) {
File uploadFile = new File(filename);
try {
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
upload(fileInputStream, server, params, fileKey, fileName, mimeType, callbackId);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}

}


public void upload(InputStream fileInputStream, String server, JSONObject params, final String fileKey, final String fileName, final String mimeType, final String callbackId) {
try {

String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String td = "--";
String boundary = "*****com.beetight.formBoundary";

URL url = new URL(server);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

// Get cookies that have been set in our webview
CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
String cookie = cm.getCookie(server);

// allow inputs
conn.setDoInput(true);
// allow outputs
conn.setDoOutput(true);
// don't use a cached copy
conn.setUseCaches(false);
// use a post method
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
// set post headers
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
// open data output stream
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

try {
for (Iterator iter = params.keys(); iter.hasNext();) {
Object key = iter.next();
dos.writeBytes(td + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"; ");
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(params.getString(key.toString()));
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}


dos.writeBytes(td + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fileKey + "\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + mimeType + lineEnd);

dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
// create a buffer of maximum size
int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
final int total = bytesAvailable;
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "available: " + bytesAvailable);

int maxBufferSize = 1024;
int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
// read file and write it into form...
int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
int progress = bytesRead;
int send = 0;
while (bytesRead > 0)
{
dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
progress += bytesRead;
final int prog = progress;
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "read " + progress + " of " + total);

// Sending every progress event is overkill
if (send++ % 20 == 0) {
ctx.runOnUiThread(new Runnable () {
public void run() {
try {
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
result.put("status", FileUploader.Status.PROGRESS);
result.put("progress", prog);
result.put("total", total);
PluginResult progressResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, result);
progressResult.setKeepCallback(true);
success(progressResult, callbackId);
} catch (JSONException e) {
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
}
});
// Give a chance for the progress to be sent to javascript
Thread.sleep(100);
}
}
// send multipart form data necessary after file data...
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(td + boundary + td + lineEnd);

// close streams
fileInputStream.close();
dos.flush();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
int ch;
StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ) {
b.append( (char)ch );
}
String s=b.toString();
dos.close();
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
result.put("status", FileUploader.Status.COMPLETE);

result.put("progress", progress);
result.put("total", total);
result.put("result", s);
PluginResult progressResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, result);
progressResult.setKeepCallback(true);
success(progressResult, callbackId);

}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
error(result, callbackId);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
error(result, callbackId);
}
catch (IOException e) {
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.IO_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
error(result, callbackId);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
error(result, callbackId);
} catch (JSONException e) {
Log.e("PhoneGapLog", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
error(result, callbackId);
}
}

public enum Status {
PROGRESS,
COMPLETE
}


}
```

This is my **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap Demo With JQuery Mobile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pgandjqm-style-override.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.2.min"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>

    <!-- CDN Respositories: For production, replace lines above with these uncommented minified versions -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />-->
    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="fileuploader.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
  <h1>file uploader</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my **fileuploader.js**:

```
FileUploader.prototype.uploadByUri = function(server, file, params, fileKey, fileName, mimeType, callback, fail) {

    return PhoneGap.exec(function(args) {
        callback(args);
    }, function(args) {
if(typeof fail == 'function') {
fail(args);
}
    }, 'FileUploader', 'uploadByUri', [server, file, params, fileKey, fileName, mimeType]);
};
FileUploader.prototype.upload = function(server, file, params, fileKey, fileName, mimeType, callback, fail) {

    return PhoneGap.exec(function(args) {
if(typeof callback == 'function') {
callback(args);
}
    }, function(args) {
if(typeof fail == 'function') {
fail(args);
}
    }, 'FileUploader', 'upload', [server, file, params, fileKey, fileName, mimeType]);
};


FileUploader.Status = {
PROGRESS: "PROGRESS",
COMPLETE: "COMPLETE"
}

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
PhoneGap.addPlugin('fileUploader', new FileUploader());
PluginManager.addService("FileUploader","com.beetight.FileUploader");
});
```

This is my whole code.. but whenever i run this project then i does nothing. I dont know where should i pass actual parameter of my server name, file to which i want to upload on server. so please suggest me how can i give my servername and name of that file to which i want to upload on server. i am very fresher in phonegap programing.
    Thnak you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code it expects something like

```
var uploader = FileUploader();
uploader.upload("http://yourserver-here.com", //<-- this is where you put your server
        "myfile.txt", //<-- The file you want to upload
        {} , //Not sure what this parameters is for, perhaps adding QS to server path
        "file", //Filekey, using the default from Fileuploader.java
        "myfile.txt", //filename
        "text/plain", //file mime-type
        function(args) {     //callback.
           alert("Callback"); //Not sure if this means success or if you have to check args
        },
        function(args) {     //callback on failure.
           alert("Failed");
        });
```